# ReactNative ActivityIndicator not showing when animating property initiate false

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm playing with react native and got a strange behaviour.

When I try to show a **ActitvityIndicator** for Android setting its *animating* property to true with a `showProgress` variable in the state it doesn't work if the variable is started as false.

In the sample below if the ActivityIndicator animating property start as true, then the buttons make the ActivityIndicator hide or appear correctly.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  TouchableHighlight,
  ActivityIndicator
} from 'react-native';

export class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            showProgress: true
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>

                <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.progressOff.bind(this)}>
                    <Text>progressOff</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>

                <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.progressOn.bind(this)}>
                    <Text>progressOn</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>

                <ActivityIndicator animating={this.state.showProgress} size="large"/>
            </View>
        );
    }

    progressOff() {
        this.setState({showProgress: false}); 
    }

    progressOn() {
        this.setState({showProgress: true});
    }
}
```

But if i use the code below, with the animating property starting as false, then the button to make the ActivityIndicator appear doesn't work:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  TouchableHighlight,
  ActivityIndicator
} from 'react-native';

export class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            showProgress: false
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>

                <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.progressOff.bind(this)}>
                    <Text>progressOff</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>

                <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.progressOn.bind(this)}>
                    <Text>progressOn</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>

                <ActivityIndicator animating={this.state.showProgress} size="large"/>
            </View>
        );
    }

    progressOff() {
        this.setState({showProgress: false}); 
    }

    progressOn() {
        this.setState({showProgress: true});
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is that for ios ? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/activityindicator.html#hideswhenstopped . By default it   hides when animating is false

Comment: I had same problem and couldn't get it to work properly. I ended up with visually hiding the indicator (`{height:0}`) when state was false.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in React Native. The code with initial state being `showProgress: false` works on iOS but not on Android.

I've opened an issue on github if you want to follow the progression:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9023

**Option 1**

A workaround I've used is to use the `showProgress` variable to render a completely different view with the `ActivityIndicator`:

```
render() {
    if (this.state.showProgress) {
        return this.renderLoadingView();
    } else {
        return this.renderMainView();
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

You can also set the opacity of the `ActivityIndicator` according to the state:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View>

            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.progressOff.bind(this)}>
                <Text>progressOff</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>

            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.progressOn.bind(this)}>
                <Text>progressOn</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>

            <ActivityIndicator style={{opacity: this.state.showProgress ? 1.0 : 0.0}} animating={true} size="large"/>
        </View>
    );
}
```

However the spinner animation doesn't always start at the same position when using this method.

Comment: Option 1 is the way to go and use this.forceUpdate() to force an update

Comment: @HimalayanCoder if you store the `showProgress` variable in `this.state`, changing it via `this.setState()` will trigger a re-render automatically. No need to use `forceUpdate()`

Comment: I've set `animating` to true but it is still not showing -_-"

Comment: {this.state.animating && <ActivityIndicator ...} Option 1 works for me

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug of React-Native for component Activity Indicator. 
I am not sure that fb has already solved it but you can try this

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            opacity: 0
        };
    }
```

to show it use this.setState({opacity:1}) and to hide again this.setState({opacity:0}) in your called functions

and in the render where you are using activity indicator

```
 <ActivityIndicator
    animating={true}
    color="#ffffff"
    style={{height: 80, marginTop: 10, opacity: this.state.opacity }}
    size="large"/>
```

Comment: smart solution!

Answer (score 3):

If in your project you can use third party components, I recommend the use of [react-native-loading-spinner-overlay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-loading-spinner-overlay)

Solved easily our problems, beacause this component use a similar way to show or hide the Activity with the property `visible`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way I found effective to work around that problem without much code is:

```
{ this.state.showProgress &&
  <ActivityIndicator animating={true} size="large"/>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried a different approach which I think that it is a more "react way" to solve problems. So, the problems with the `opacity` solution is that If you just set it to 0, it still will be a animation, so it is not the best solution thinking in your app performance.

I created a separated component that I called `<Loading/>`, here is the code:

```
import { ActivityIndicator } from "react-native"
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

const Loading = (props) =>
    props.animating
        ? <ActivityIndicator style={props.style} 
               importantForAccessibility='auto' size={props.size} 
                     color={props.size} /> : null

Loading.propTypes = {
    animating: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    style: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.style, PropTypes.object]),
}

export default Loading
```

Usage:

```
<Loading animating={true} importantForAccessibility='auto' size="large" color="#A02BFF" style={styles.loading} />
```

That way it will avoid to create a animation when it is not a necessity, you will create separated component that can be removed easily at the point that the [ActivityIndicator issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9023) becomes solved in the future by replacing it to the original ActivityIndicator native component.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I had with this, was that in Android it wasn't visible because of the background I had on my screen. I fixed by only changing the color prop to something I knew should stand out in the background:

`<ActivityIndicator color={theme.secondary.color} />`

Answer (score 0):

i got this problem all by a mistake. i did not put `ActivityIndeicator` in the center of a view. so it positioned on top of a view, which is covered by a natigation bar. code below is correct. hope this can help u.

```
<View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
  <ActivityIndicator
    animating={true}
    style={
      {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        opacity: this.state.loading ? 1 : 0
      }}
    size="large"
  />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

**A quick fix Use conditional rendering**.. Keep animating : {true} and just Visible and invisible view.

Checkout :

https://kylewbanks.com/blog/how-to-conditionally-render-a-component-in-react-native

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for react native version 0.59.10 , the size property type is different for Android and iOS, so for that I had to make a Platform check as following and it worked.

```
<ActivityIndicator 
                size={Platform.OS === "ios" ? 0 : "large"} //This platform check worked.
                color={props.color} 
                animating={props.animating}
                style={props.style}
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

The transition of `animating` from `false` to `true` is too slow on Android. But you can force a re-render using the `key` prop:

```js
<ActivityIndicator
  key={`${props.animating}`}
  animating={props.animating}
/>
```

When `props.animating` changes from `false` to `true`, they key also changes. This forces a re-render, meaning that a new component is rendered with `animating = true`, which will instantly start your spinner.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing it on Android one of the reason could be the color property.

Be sure to give the ActivityIndicator a color. For example:

```
<ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution work perfectly for me in Android.

Hope this will help you.

```
import {ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';

const [opacity, setOpacity] = useState(0)

const onLoadStart = () => {
   setOpacity(1);
};

const onLoad = () => {
   setOpacity(0);
};

const onBuffer = ({isBuffering}) => {
   setOpacity(isBuffering ? 1 : 0);
};

return(
<View>
  <Video
    video={{uri: props.videoSource}}
    autoplay={false}
    customStyles={{
      seekBarProgress: {
        backgroundColor: theme.color.primary,
      },
      seekBarKnob: {
        backgroundColor: theme.color.primary,
      },
    }}
    ref={ref => (player = ref)}
    onBuffer={onBuffer}
    onLoadStart={onLoadStart}
    onLoad={onLoad}
  />
  <ActivityIndicator
    animating
    size="large"
    color={color.primarylight}
    style={{
      opacity: opacity,
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 70,
      left: 70,
      right: 70,
      // height: 50,
    }}
  />
</View>
```

)