# ReactNative ActivityIndicator not showing EVEN when animating property is TRUE and opactity 1

Tags: javascript, react-native

i am new to react native ...Before you  mention external links i  already searched googgle and  read [ReactNative ActivityIndicator not showing when animating property initiate false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579665/reactnative-activityindicator-not-showing-when-animating-property-initiate-false) and bug ...
have  tried most of thing there..
i have set   animating property is TRUE and opactity 1 ..could you please help

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ActivityIndicator, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class Login extends Component {
  onPressLearnMore = () => {
    alert(5);
  }
  render() {
    return <View >
      <Button
        onPress={this.onPressLearnMore}
        title="Learn More"
        color="#841584"
        accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
      />
      <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#00ff00" animating={true} style={
        {
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          opacity: 1.0,
          height: 200,
        }} />
      <Button
        onPress={this.onPressLearnMore}
        title="Learn More"
        color="#841584"
        accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
      />
    </View>;
  }
}
```

Comment: This code works perfectly fine. Just pasted on a new RN project and work as expected. Do you have this component nested inside some other View?

Comment: no just this component only  (apprears when app start )..created a new app with blank and started DOCS on react native ...i hosted it on redmi note 3  ..tried everythng ...ok will  crete new react app with  tempalte and all features  and  update

Comment: @AlexSanchez thnsk it was working  already turns out in developer option of android...i had  turned off  Windows/transitions and animoator duration  from 2x to oFF ( for speed purpose )  . i turend  then to 2x it worked

Answer (score 0):

in andoid setting in developer options make sure your

```
window animation :altlest 1x

transition animation :altlest 1x

animator duration scale  :altlest 1x
```